# Manually (Re-)Encrypting a Whatsapp Backup File

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, encryption

### Problem

So, after rooting using a custom ROM and rooting my phone somehow WhatsApp wont let me back up my chat history anymore, see below. The problem now is that I want to transfer my chat history from my old phone to a new one.

[image: Unable to backup messages]
.

### Alternative Plan

From what I've gathered WhatsApp Backup files are crypt12 encrypted msgstore.db files that are located at the root directory /data/data/com.whatsapp

**Things I have:**

- Old Backup from a few months ago
- my current unencrypted msgstore.db through root access
- crypt12 key file through root access

My plan now is to basically create a new backup by encrypting my current msgstore.db and transfering that to the new phone, hopefully recovering my chats. **The only thing I need is a way to reencrypt the file** to be the same as a WhatsApp Backup File. Or just modifying my existing, old backup with the new content. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm confused. From the problem, it seems like backing up is not working, but from your solution, it looks like you are trying to restore old messages. So which one is it?

Comment: WhatsApp's native backup function seems to be broken for some reason and I cant get it to backup locally. However I do have access to the msgstore.db which is what a backup contains. I want to transfer that to my new phone with but I need to wrap it as a backup file first so Whatsapp will accept it and I can restore it like a normal backup on my new phone.

Comment: oh, I didn't realize you are trying to transfer to a different phone. I can't give any good ideas on how to reencript, but did you try saving to Google drive?

Comment: I had the same problem when I bought my phone last year. But my chats were not very important, so I didn't researched for a solution for too long to know how to solve it...

Comment: @ABochur Saving it to google drive works by creating a local backup first, then uploading it to the drive so same problem...

Comment: @Syntic Were you able to solve this i.e. re-encrypt the file?